# How to remove an item from GridView's LookupEdit if item is selected above

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress, lookup

I have a gridview which has a LookUpEdit. Lets say, in the grid's first row, I select a value from the LookupEdit. When I go to the second row, I shouldnt see the the selected value in the first row.

here is my grid below...

"HM-6.4.2016-B-001" is selected on the first row, how can I remove that value on the second row?

[image]

Comment: Handle ShowingEditor or ShownEditor event and there you can initialize cell editor data source as per your requirement

Comment: You really want to remove or just hide the value? If you want to remove a value in a DataSource bound component (like Grid), you should always realize this in your DataSource. So just set the bounded value string.empty for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, set the `LookUpEdit.Properties.AllowNullInput` property to `DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.True`.

In this case, it is sufficient to press the `CTRL`+`DELETE` key combination to clear the value.

Thanks